How to Display Row Percentages (Prevalence) Instead of Column Percentages in table1 Package in R?
I am using the table1 package in R to generate descriptive statistics stratified by a variable (e.g., HIV status). By default, the package provides column percentages, showing the proportion of each category within the levels of the stratification variable. However, I need to calculate and display row percentages instead — that is, the prevalence of the stratification variable within each demographic category.
For example, if I have HIVPOS (0 = No, 1 = Yes) as the stratification variable and demographic variables like SEXBIRTH (Gender) or RACE_1 (Ethnicity), the default output looks like this (with column percentages):



Variable
Category
N (HIV-)
% (HIV-)
N (HIV+)
% (HIV+)




SEXBIRTH
Male
200
44.4%
300
66.7%



Female
250
55.6%
150
33.3%


RACE_1
White
300
66.7%
100
22.2%



Black
100
22.2%
300
66.7%


AGEATVIS
Mean (SD)
40 (10)
N/A
45 (15)
N/A


BSEDUCTN
Less than high school
150
33.3%
250
55.6%



High school graduate
200
44.4%
200
44.4%


EMPLOYMT
Full-time
200
44.4%
150
33.3%



Part-time
100
22.2%
100
22.2%


CURSMOKE
Current smoker
150
33.3%
250
55.6%



Non-smoker
300
66.7%
200
44.4%


POTUSE
Yes
250
55.6%
150
33.3%



No
200
44.4%
300
66.7%


kidfail60
No
300
66.7%
400
88.9%



Yes
150
33.3%
250
55.6%



Instead, I want to display row percentages similarly like this:



Variable
Category
Count (HIV-)
Count (HIV+)
Row % (HIV+)




SEXBIRTH
Male
200
300
60.0%



Female
250
150
37.5%


RACE_1
White
300
100
25.0%



Black
100
300
75.0%


AGEATVIS
Mean (SD)
40 (10)
45 (15)
N/A


BSEDUCTN
Less than high school
150
250
62.5%



High school graduate
200
200
50.0%


EMPLOYMT
Full-time
200
150
42.9%



Part-time
100
100
50.0%


CURSMOKE
Current smoker
150
250
62.5%



Non-smoker
300
200
40.0%


POTUSE
Yes
250
150
37.5%



No
200
300
60.0%


kidfail60
No
300
400
57.1%



Yes
150
250
62.5%



Here’s a simplified version of the code I’m currently using:
R
table1(~ 
  SEXBIRTH + RACE_1 + AGEATVIS | factor(HIVPOS),
  data = mydata,
  render.categorical = "FREQ (PCTnoNA%)", 
  render.continuous = "Mean (SD)",
  overall = FALSE
)

I explored the following approaches but haven't been able to generate row percentages:
Modifying the render.categorical function to calculate row percentages.
Switching to other packages like gtsummary, flextable, or kableExtra, but couldn’t find built-in functionality for row percentages.
Questions:
Is it possible to calculate and display row percentages in table1?
If not, which R package or method would you recommend to achieve this formatting?
Are there any custom modifications or workflows I should consider?
Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated!

Is the issue that you don't want to switch the  variables to the other order.  I would read your code as "sex given HIV status"  and I think you want "HIV status given Sex" or HIVPOS| SEXBIRTH.

This issue report shows some code that might do what you want https://github.com/benjaminrich/table1/issues/38

Does gtsummary::tbl_summary(percent = "row") get you what you want?

I found a solution using summarise. But I am not sure if there is a better solution available. See code below.


I found a solution using summarise and group by. There may be better solution, however, I will paste mine here.
# List of variables to include
vars_to_analyze <- c(
  "HIVPOS", "SEXBIRTH", "RACE_1", "BSEDUCTN", "MARSTAT", "EMPLOYMT", "INCOME", 
  "Has_diabetes",          # Diabetes status
  "HTN"          ,         # Hypertension
  "Has_depression",        # Depression status
  "CURSMOKE", "SMKGRP", "BINGE", "POTUSE", "COCUSE", 
  "HERUSE", "ODRGUSE", "IDU"
)

# Create a lookup table for row percentages
freq_table <- data_filtered %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = all_of(vars_to_analyze), names_to = "Variable", values_to = "Category") %>%
  group_by(Variable, Category, kidfail60) %>%
  summarise(N = n(), .groups = "drop") %>%
  group_by(Variable, Category) %>%
  mutate(Row_Pct = 100 * N / sum(N, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup()

# Inspect the table
print(freq_table)

# Ensure the Variable column follows the specified sequence
freq_table_ordered <- freq_table %>%
  mutate(Variable = factor(Variable, levels = vars_to_analyze)) %>%
  arrange(Variable, Category)

# Rearrange the table to make it wider
freq_table_wide <- freq_table_ordered %>%
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = kidfail60, 
    values_from = c(N, Row_Pct),
    names_glue = "{.value}_kidfail60_{kidfail60}"
  )

# Inspect the rearranged table
print(freq_table_wide)

Output is below.
A tibble: 75 × 6
   Variable Category                           N_kidfail60_0 N_kidfail60_1 Row_Pct_kidfail60_0 Row_Pct_kidfail60_1
   <fct>    <fct>                                      <int>         <int>               <dbl>               <dbl>
 1 HIVPOS   HIV positive                                1328           294                81.9               18.1 
 2 HIVPOS   HIV seronegative                             820            88                90.3                9.69
 3 SEXBIRTH Female                                      1427           285                83.4               16.6 
 4 SEXBIRTH Male                                         721            97                88.1               11.9 
 5 RACE_1   0.NON-HISPANIC WHITE                         502            70                87.8               12.2 
 6 RACE_1   1.NON-HISPANIC BLACK                        1301           260                83.3               16.7 
 7 RACE_1   1.NON-HISPANIC OTHER                          77            17                81.9               18.1 
 8 RACE_1   2.HISPANIC                                   268            35                88.4               11.6 

